# Относительное местоимение "что" для обозначения персон

Tags: грамотная-речь, союзы, переводы, местоимение

**Go find all those you can find and bring them to me.**

Перевела (очень и очень грубо) так:

*Приведи мне всех тех, **что** ты найдешь.*

Вопрос: можно ли использовать ***что***, если речь идет об одушевленных персонах, которые должны быть найдены?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Как мне кажется, в современном языке более подходящим будет такой перевод: **Приведи мне всех тех, кого ты найдешь.**

Союз ЧТО также используется, но он уже не кажется естественным **для одушевленных предметов.** К примеру, в Нацкорпусе конструкция "всех, кто" встречается 2472 раза.  Один из примеров: Популярное издание для всех, кто любит и знает русскую песню.

Еще один довод не в пользу союзного слова ЧТО (= КОТОРЫЙ): дело в том, что **оно не отличается от союза со значением следствия.**

**Сравнить:**

(1) Дай бог, чтобы сохранились **такие** люди, **что** ставят во главу угла интересы дела (союзное слово ЧТО).

**Примечание.** Обратим здесь внимание на указательное слово с качественным выделением: ТАКОЙ, а не ТОТ. Если уж союзное слово ЧТО используется, то обычно при выделении (такой), а не при распространении (тот).

(2) Он такой человек, **что** пойдет на всё ради денег (союз ЧТО со значением следствия).

Answer (score 1):

Это нормальная разговорная конструкция.

> Он был довольно щедр в пути и потому вполне верил в заботливость
>   **всех тех, что** кормили и поили его, с утра до вечера служили ему, 
>   предупреждая его малейшее желание, охраняли его чистоту и покой,
>   таскали его вещи, звали для него носильщиков, доставляли его сундуки в
>   гостиницы.

(Бунин)

> В конце пути, в далекой стороне,
>   Под гром пальбы прощались мы впервые
>   **Со всеми, что** погибли на войне,
>   Как с мертвыми прощаются живые.

(Г. Бакланов)

> А без душёнки, какова есть, ей Богу плохо жить ― она равняет **со
>   всеми, что** при малых чинах, приятно и заставляет прямо смотреть во
>   все глаза.

(Анненков - письмо Тургеневу)

*Все цитаты - из Нацкорпуса.*

Здесь *"что"* в значении *"которых", "которые", "которыми", "какие", "каковые"*  и так далее. Можно спорить, насколько уместна такая конструкция в современном литературном языке, но совершенно точно этот спор не имеет отношения к одушевленности объектов или персон, о которых идет повествование.